# fwrite/fread struct with bitfields and char *

Tags: c, struct, fwrite, bit-fields

I am testing a custom structure where there is bitfield and a unsigned char * (that will be allocated later).

Here is the structure :

```
struct test {
  unsigned int field1 : 1;
  unsigned int field2 : 15;
  unsigned int field3 : 32;
  unsigned int dataLength : 16;
  unsigned char * data;
}
```

The problem is when I tried to save this struct inside a file in hex.

For example :

```
int writeStruct(struct test *ptr, FILE *f) {

   // for data, suppose I know the length by dataLength  : 
   // this throw me : cannot take adress of bit field
   int count;
   count = fwrite( &(ptr->field2), sizeof(unsigned int), 1, f);

   // this throw me : makes pointer to integer without a cast
   count = fwrite( ptr->field2, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, f);

   // same for length
   count = fwrite( htons(ptr->data) , ptr->dataLength, 1,f);       

   // so , how to do that ?
}
```

The same problem goes to fread :

```
int readAnStructFromFile(struct test *ptr, FILE *f) {
   // probably wrong
   fread(ptr->field1, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, f);
}
```

So , how can I write/read struct like this ?

Thanks for your help

PS for fread, this could work if there wasn't these bitfields: [How to fread() structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721808/how-to-fread-structs)

Comment: While using bitfields for `field1` and `field2` seems to make sense, since they are not standard bit-widths, it makes less sense for `field3` and `dataLenght`, which could use `uint32_t` and `uint16_t` respectively. And if you're not on a memory-constrained system, there's often no need for bitfields at all (and then use `size_t` for the `dataLength` member) unless you are trying to match some other data-structure (network packet, on-disk structure, or similar).

Comment: It is an example to handle several case :). I tried to make a custom network packet ^^

Comment: Do you really require to store the file in Binary format? Why not something like `json`, etc.? Which would be easier to read back due to consistent file text structure using `fscanf` and `fprintf`.

Comment: Yes, it should be in binary so that something else transfers it ..

Comment: Do you understand what the `s` stands for in `htons()`?

Comment: I don't think so ... short ?

Comment: 1) You cannot take the address of a bitfield, it has no address. 2) you can fwrite() the entire structure in one call,though.

Comment: fwrite with an pointer inside the struct ? The last time I have done something like that, it didn't work ^^

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to get an address of a bitfield. The usual way to handle it is to either use a temporary variable on read/write sides or just to save the whole struct as a single entity. With temp vars it looks like the following:

```
int count;
int field2 = ptr->field2;
count = fwrite( &field2, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, f);
...
int field1;
fread(&field1, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, f);
ptr->field1 = field1;
```

or for the whole struct:

```
count = fwrite( ptr, sizeof(struct test), 1, f);
```

Comment: thanks : i will test your first idea. Do you think the whole struct fwrite will not work because of the pointer inside ?

Comment: In your case the whole struct write will not work. It will not write the data itself, just the data pointer which makes no sense.

Comment: The suggestion is to split it in 2 parts: header and the data. The header you would be able to write as a whole